# PHP echo get value shows <br> tag

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

[The issue has resolved itself for some reason.]

I've had this piece of code for quite a while now with no issues whatsoever. Today I started getting to work and got an uncaught syntax error, telling me there was a stray "<". I located it and it's a piece of javascript code that gets the id value of the post you are looking at (on the forum).

The code is used for deleting a post using AJAX.

```
    $('.deletePost').click(function() {
        var delPost = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this post?');

        if (delPost == true) {
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var getId = <?php echo $_GET['id'] ?>

            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    location.replace('index');
                }
            }
            xhttp.open('GET', 'deletepost.php?id=' + getId, true);
            xhttp.send();
        }

        return false;

    });
```

When loading up the actual website, the `getId` variable is `<br >`

This code is located in the 'footer.php' file, I use `include` to get it on every page on the website.

First off I use jQuery click to execute this, so the syntax error shouldn't really be a problem on other pages, as I made sure to not use the `.deletePost` class on anything on any of the other files. Second, it also needs the user to click OK and make the variable true, so to me this just makes no sense.

The biggest problem is that it makes all the other javascript code both above and below it useless.

(I'm not sure if any more code is relevant and I didn't want to make this too long, so please let me know if I need to include anything else.)

ID in `$_GET['id']` is generated like so:

`

```
$sql = '
        SELECT c.cat_name, c.cat_id, c.cat_description, t.topic_id, t.topic_by, t.topic_subject, t.topic_date
        FROM categories c LEFT JOIN topics t ON c.cat_id=t.topic_cat
        WHERE topic_date = ( SELECT MAX(t2.topic_date) FROM topics t2 WHERE t2.topic_cat = t.topic_cat ) AND c.cat_id<4
        ORDER BY t.topic_date DESC
        ';

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if (!$result) {
        echo 'Could not display categories. Error: ';// . mysqli_error($conn);
    } else {
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
            echo 'No categories found in the database.';
        } else {
            echo '
                <table>
                <h3>Latest topics in categories</h3>
                <tr>
                    <th>Category</th>
                    <th>Latest Topic</th>
                </tr>
            ';

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                echo '<tr>
                    <td class="leftpart">
                        <h3><a href="category?id=' . $row['cat_id'] . '">' . $row['cat_name'] . '</a></h3>' . $row['cat_description'] . '
                    </td>
                    <td class="rightpart">
                        <a href="topic?id=' . $row['topic_id'] . '">' . $row['topic_subject'] . '<br>By <b>' . $row['topic_by'] . '</b></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                ';
            }

            echo '</table>';
        }
    }`
```

This is the error. It appears in F12.
[image: Error (Displays in F12)]

Comment: What does `<?php echo $_GET['id'] ?>` return ?

Comment: @drip Refresh the page, somehow I forgot to include it and did it after posting the question

Comment: If it returns a string, wrap you php code in quotes like this: `var getId = '<?php echo $_GET['id'] ?>';`

Comment: @MohammadMudassir tried it now, doesn't seem to work

Comment: Show the HTML where `id` of `$_GET['id']` is generated

Comment: put in js code console.log(getId); try to see what value it is getting in console

Comment: @RST I'm not entirely sure if that is what you meant, but Its done now

Comment: You said the variable becomes `<br>` but that is not true. That is just part of the errormessage. The errormessage says `id` is not defined. What does the url look like which is displayed when you hover over the generated link?

Comment: @RST alright, that makes more sense. The URL is fine. Ex: `webpage.com/topic?id=20`. When I am on the topic page everything works fine, I can delete the topic and all the other js code works just fine. This just occurs on all the other pages except for the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use quotes around the php statement 
like this. And make sure on the server side typecast the id value to integer

```
var getId = "<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>";
```

first make sure that the GET parameter gets the id value correctly, check on the inspect element in browser , If your Id populated correctly from database it should be like this (I don't know your Ids and values)

```
<h3><a href="topic?id=1">correct cat name</a></h3>correct cat_description
```

And the GET parameter need a key "id" to get its value. The error saying that the "id" is not there at the URL as a GET parameter.

check the URL address also it should contain an "id" parameter

If your id from the database is some sort of string. enclose the string inside `urlencode($row['cat_id'])` function.

Other than that i don't see any errors. Pardon me if i misunderstood the question

Comment: I'll have to look into the typecasting, but are the quotes really necessary? The JS works perfectly on the page where it's supposed to, it just screws everything up on the pages where it's supposed to just be there without doing anything.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to use the semicolon inside the php statement

Comment: The quotes are necessary because without quotes the <?php .. ?> statement will always consider as a part of js script and throws a syntax error

Comment: Same error still, also, by typecasting the id value, do you mean in the database, or so that the script only recognizes it as an integer?

Comment: first make sure that the GET parameter gets the id value correctly, check on the inspect element in browser , If your Id populated correctly from database it sholud be like this

Comment: @ArchuSm with the new information do you think you can give a correct answer by yourself or do I have to add a comment to the post so you can act on that?

Comment: I'm having some really weird behavior here. Like mentioned in the question, it has worked for several weeks without problems, it was just when i got started on working on it today this occured. After taking a break and getting back the code works just fine again. Gotta love programming